# Performing Javascript floating point arithmetic in Python

Tags: javascript, python, floating-point

I am writing a Python program which interacts with a webapp which I did not write. There is some state that I need to represent in my program which is not sent to the (javascript) client by the server, but is instead computed separately on both the client and the server with shared information.

For example, the exchange might go something like:

```
var x = getValueFromServer(); //client gets 0.73346
x *= 1 << 30;
result = x & 1023
```

My Python code successfully receives 0.73346, but I need the value of `result`. The result of the multiplication by 2^30 seems to be the same in javascript and Python, but I cannot directly mask the float value inside Python.

I have tried (for the above example value)

```
from struct import pack, unpack
unpack('q', pack('d', 0.73346))[0] & 1023
```

but this gives a value of 696 in Python, while when I run the above javascript in node I get a value of 566. I've also tried a few other combinations of packing and unpacking formats, with no success.

My last resort would be executing javascript from inside Python with a node subprocess, but I'd prefer to avoid that. How can I solve this?

Comment: How is python receiving the data to be used?

Comment: A websocket. That isn't particularly relevant here though. Technically it's not receiving a float directly, it receives some integers and computes the float, so there's no issue with decoding the float that is being used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `struct`: that would be reinterpreting the bit pattern of the float as an integer, rather than doing something resembling an arithmetic operation. Does something like `int(0.73346 * (1 << 30)) & 1023` do what you want?

Comment: Right so the expression you provided does not work in python, as bitwise operations aren't defined for floats. The unpack operation was an attempt to keep the bit order the same and allow that operation.

Comment: Did you try it? It works for me at the command line (in both Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: Oh whoops I didn't notice the bitwise operation was outside the int call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = 0.73346
x = x * (1 << 30)
x = int(x) & 1023
```

gives 566 in python

Comment: Ah it appears that the way javascript lets you use bitwise operations on floats is by casting them to ints... I didn't even consider that. Thanks!